# instalar netcdf en python windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, windows, windows10

quisiera saber como instalar la libreria netcdf en python, en Windows. Nunca instalé una librería allí, así que me gustaría aprender a hacerlo. 
Saludos,
Florencia.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo asi:

primero debes instalar **numpy** y luego **netcdf**:

```
pip install numpy
pip install netcdf4
```

Comment: No me permite realizar la instalación. 
Voy a la terminal de IPython y pongo: pip install numpy
Y obtengo:
File "<ipython-input-1-700e356ac91d>", line 1
    pip install numpy
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Por lo que entiendo el error de sintaxis lo identifica en 'install'

Comment: @Florencia No es un comando que debas teclear dentro de un intérprete python, sino directamente en una terminal windows. En todo caso, según cómo hayas instalado antes Python el método de instalación de paquetes adicionales puede variar. Si Python lo instalaste a través de Anaconda, entonces el comando `conda` es el que te permite instalar más cosas. También deberías familiarizarte con entornos virtuales para evitar instalar paquetes "globalmente".

Comment: @abulafia gracias por la ayuda, me ha sido muy útil !! 
Lo que hice fue desde la terminal de windows, como instalé Python a través de Anaconda fue poner conda install netCDF4